# Magento 2: PWA : FetchError: request to https://local.magento.com/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Tags: magento2, error, pwa

Please help me? I got an error when **yarn run build**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved 
Create SSL certificate for **https//local.magento.com**:

Comment: can you mention here - How to create an SSL certificate for the localhost domain Magento setup?

Comment: Created. Doesn't work.