# Magento 2: PWA : FetchError: request to https://magentolocal.com/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 162.255.119.134:443

Tags: magento2, pwa, docker, vagrant

i'm getting this error when docker/run docker

I'm running PWA Studio on Docker with backend on Vagrant Homestead.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: PWA : FetchError: request to https://local.magento.com/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305117/magento-2-pwa-fetcherror-request-to-https-local-magento-com-graphql-failed)

Comment: @BenCrook Nope. SSL certificate is already there.

Comment: Ah sorry, that is an automated message because I flagged this as a duplicate question as they're identical.